# Retrofit Headers Not Working Issue

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Postman to hit server GET call with url. and adding headers like below in headers sections in postman  so when run in postman it works and send data in body but In android using Retrofit not working with 401 error.

```
X-APIClient: {"apiClientId":"testing-account-cli","apiToken":"$2y$10$C/quaRQUsrWa30hjQJuckOXbW9kIZ.W3G1TlLMYg6lr/XDUes7SM."}
X-Header-Request: {"deviceId":"ffffffff-daac-6513-4eca-0c41298e00df"}
```

And It works on Postman. But In Android with Retrofit, it's not working 401 error.

1)

```
   @GET("user-list")
   Call<User> getUsers(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

2)

```
    public static Map<String,String> addCustomHeaders()
    {
        headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("X-APIClient",
                "\"apiClientId\":\"testing-account-cli\",\"apiToken\":\"$2y$10$C/quaRQUsrWa30hjQJuckOXbW9kIZ.W3G1TlLMYg6lr/XDUes7SM.");
        headers.put("X-Header-Request", "\"deviceId\":\"ffffffff-daac-6513-4eca-0c41298e00df")
        ;
        return headers;
    }
```

3) Calling GET using below fails always

```
 Call<User> call = api.getUsers(RetrofitClient.addCustomHeaders());


        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "GET User Success." + response.body().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "GET Failed Users." + t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

Please Help whats wrong. As its always throwing 401 with authentication false and authorization false.

Answer (score 2):

Try function below, I separated headers.

```
    public static Map<String,String> addCustomHeaders()
{
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("apiClientId" ,"testing-account-cli");
    headers.put("apiToken", "$2y$10$C/quaRQUsrWa30hjQJuckOXbW9kIZ.W3G1TlLMYg6lr/XDUes7SM.");
    headers.put("deviceId","ffffffff-daac-6513-4eca-0c41298e00df");
    return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interceptor for header

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
 @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
 Request request = chain.request();
request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("apiClientId", "testing-account-cli")
 .header("apiToken","$2y$10$C/quaRQUsrWa30hjQJuckOXbW9kIZ.W3G1TlLMYg6lr/XDUes7SM.")
.header("deviceId","ffffffff-daac-6513-4eca-0c41298e00df")
                    .build()
 Response response = chain.proceed(request);
  return response;
}
```

//add this class into retrofit class like

```
.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
```